# Removing index.php - Controller Methods not working

Tags: codeigniter

I have codeigniter app in home directory. Sym link created in /var/www/html. I made changes to incldue .htaccess file in application folder to remove index.php in URL. The below link works fine.

```
http://mydomain.net/dms/welcome
```

That is, default method of controller works fine. But when I have method 'test' in welcome controller, the following link results in HTTP 404 webpage not found error.

```
http://mydomain.net/dms/welcome/test
```

Code igniter 2.1.1 directory:

```
dms
    application
    system
    index.php
    .htaccess
```

Config.php

```
$config['base_url']     = '';
$config['index_page'] = ""; 
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

Config file httpd.conf

```
Alias /dms/ "/var/www/html/dms/"
<Directory "/var/www/html/dms">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Sym links

```
ls -l /var/www/html
dms -> /home/user1/dms
```

.htaccess file

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

I also tried with the following 2 Rewrite rules in place of above rules in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But contoller method cant be accessed without using index.php in URL. Having spent much time in this, I think it is something to do with Rewrite rules. Could some one guide me on this.

Comment: my server is redhat. rewrite module is loaded in httpd.conf. ReWrite enabled in .htaccess file as given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test this configuration for .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|.*\.css|.*\.js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /angular1/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Replace "angular1" by your correct path.

Comment: You are welcome! I add .css and .js on rule, but you could be add .jpg and others using "|" to separate on regex.