# htaccess in codeigniter to clear index.php at url

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm newbie with htacces..
I've file htaccess like this

```
    Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I called url like this without index.php it's work

```
http://localhost/url/
```

but when I try to call

```
http://localhost/url/controller/
```

and

```
http://localhost/url/controller/method/
```

the page back to xampp's home.

so what would I do? I want url without index.php.

thank you very much every advice.

Comment: it's doesn't work , i got 404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.

Comment: Do you have any other htaccess files? Specifically, any in the "controller" directory?

Comment: Your site under the `url` folder or root?

Comment: Please, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18230894/1613335, maybe it will be helpful for you

Comment: no i just have one htaccess file.

Comment: I already fixed it, I just have to add name Codeigniter folder befor index.php so I write 'RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Ci_name/index.php?/$1 [L]'

Comment: This question is resolved on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214487/removing-index-php-controller-methods-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something simple like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|media|favicon\.ico|ipadicon\.jpg)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
```